# nscanner taking value from a string

Tags: iphone, nsscanner

how can i get the value of pickey from this string.this string as such is stored in coredata and i need to extract the value of pickey.how can i do this using nscanner.which method should i use?

```
@"http://myserverIP/showpicture.php?email=mymail@yahoo.com&key=442205212&hash=63b201cacb5c07f6adbc8f3dcb408099d3450548&pickey=21342342342342341231"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"pickey=" intoString:NULL];
if ([scanner scanString:@"pickey=" intoString:NULL]) {
    long long pickeyValue = 0;
    if ([scanner scanLongLong:&pickeyValue]) {
        // Successfully found an integer value at this position
        ...
    }
}
```